# RequireJS + TypeScript workflow

Tags: typescript, requirejs

RequireJS path mappings are configured by calling `requirejs.config`. The `requirejs` object is a global variable; however, all type definitions available for RequireJS expose it as a module to be imported, rather than as a global variable.

How should I use RequireJS with TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

> How should I use RequireJS with TypeScript

If you just download this file : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/requirejs/require.d.ts and include it in your project it will work fine i.e. will make the `require` function globally available [*as seen here*](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/07378f4a20ef709de8aea9507144fcf48c38897d/requirejs/require.d.ts#L396)

## Tip

I don't recommend requirejs and recommend going all in with commonjs and using something like webpack. Intro : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: I don't recommend using anything other than requirejs, because everything else seems to need package managers and/or some manner of build infrastructure. Require just needs a couple js files and a couple lines of funky initialization code. And with Typescript, once it's set up - set module to 'amd' in tsconfig and you can just use nice fat export and import statements. It's very sugary.